# Error in FAXCOMLib (c#)

Tags: c#

I write a small program to send fax using FAXCOMLIB .

I make a class "fax" ,here is the code :

```
    internal class Fax
    {

        public  void SendFax( string FileName, string FaxNumber)
        {
            if (FaxNumber != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    FAXCOMLib.FaxServer faxServer = new FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass();
                    faxServer.Connect(Environment.MachineName);


                    FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc faxDoc = (FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc)faxServer.CreateDocument(FileName);

                    faxDoc.RecipientName = "گیرنده";
                    faxDoc.FaxNumber = FaxNumber;

                    faxDoc.DisplayName = "Asa";


                    int Response = faxDoc.Send();


                    faxServer.Disconnect();

                }
                catch (Exception Ex) { MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message); }
            }
        }
    }
```

So when i want to execute the code i got these errors:

```
1-Error 13  Interop type 'FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead

2-Error 12  The type 'FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass' has no constructors defined
```

Comment: For the assembly properties, did you set the "Embed Interop Type" to false? Did you also read the documentation on how to use the API's?

Comment: yes you should. I believe you need to understand more about how COM/Interop works

Comment: how ca i find Embed Interop Type?

Comment: in your project references, expand it and select the assembly in question (whatever the name is... FAX... whatever), then right click on it and go to properties. In there you will see the "Embed Interop Type" property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your project references, expand it and select the assembly in question (whatever the name is... FAX... whatever), then right click on it and go to properties. In there you will see the "Embed Interop Type" property - change it to "False"